# Padding gives different paddings to top and bottom

Tags: html, css

```css
html {
  font-size : 10px;
  }
body {
  text-align : center;
  color       : #9da8c1;
  font-family : sans-serif;
  background  : #013f81;
  }
h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  }
#img-div {
  background : #2a5590;
  width      : 600px;
  margin     : 0 auto;
  padding    : 10px;
  }
#conway-photo {
  height : auto;
  width  : 500px;
  }
figcaption {
  font-size  : 1.5rem;
  background : red;
  }
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <h1 id="title">John Horton Conway<h1>
  <figure id="img-div">
    <img id="conway-photo" src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/04/18/obituaries/14Conway1/14Conway1-mediumSquareAt3X-v2.jpg"</img>
    <figcaption>J.H.Conway holding a model of polyhedron</figcaption>
  <figure>
</main>
```

I have this html code and I want to have the padding in the figure so that the text and the image are the same distance from the border.
For some reason I don't know, there is more distance on the bottom than on the top. Also there is a big jump in the bottom when I switch from no padding to 10px.

Comment: fix your HTML first, then see how style behaves . img tag  doesn't require to be closed, , no content can be added : ìmg src="image_link"alt="alt text" >` . h1 & figure are  also not closed properly. Your browser might think there is a figure child to figure ... https://jsfiddle.net/L18v30er/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML tags were messed up please be sure to check your code with a HTML Validator like https://validator.w3.org/ .

I fixed up your HTML, and it appears to be working how you intend it to:

```css
html {
font-size: 10px;
}

body {
text-align: center;
color: #9da8c1;
font-family: sans-serif;
background-color: #013f81;
}

h1 {
font-size: 4rem;
}

#img-div {
background-color: #2a5590;
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
}

#conway-photo {
height: auto;
width: 500px;
}

figcaption {
font-size: 1.5rem;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<main id="main">
<h1 id="title">John Horton Conway</h1>
<figure id="img-div">
<img id="conway-photo" src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/04/18/obituaries/14Conway1/14Conway1-mediumSquareAt3X-v2.jpg">
<figcaption>J.H.Conway holding a model of polyhedron</figcaption>
</figure>
</main>
</html>
```